# OPNSense and Unifi RADIUS issue

Tags: radius, unifi, opnsense

I have an OPNSense firewall and a Unifi controller I am trying to enable Radius authentication and Radius Vlan assignment

On the unifi side I have done the following
Created an SSID
Created A radius profile
Created a network

On the OPNSense side
I created a vlan
Enabled DHCP on the vlan and gave it a /24 range
Installed and enabled FreeRadius

I am getting the following errors

```
 2021-02-27T21:03:25        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Error parsing 
client section   
 2021-02-27T21:03:25        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Failed parsing 
 configuration item "ipaddr" - Failed resolving "" to IPv4 address: Name does not resolve    
 2021-02-27T21:01:38        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Error parsing 
 client section  
 2021-02-27T21:01:38        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Failed parsing 
 configuration item "ipaddr" - Failed resolving "" to IPv4 address: Name does not resolve    
 2021-02-27T21:01:09        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Error parsing 
 client section  
 2021-02-27T21:01:09        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Failed parsing 
 configuration item "ipaddr" - Failed resolving "" to IPv4 address: Name does not resolve    
 2021-02-27T21:00:50        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Error parsing 
 client section  
 2021-02-27T21:00:50        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Failed parsing 
 configuration item "ipaddr" - Failed resolving "" to IPv4 address: Name does not resolve    
 2021-02-27T20:58:23        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Error parsing 
 client section  
 2021-02-27T20:58:23        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Failed parsing 
 configuration item "ipaddr" - Failed resolving "" to IPv4 address: Name does not resolve    
 2021-02-27T20:58:12        Error: /usr/local/etc/raddb/clients.conf[2]: Error parsing 
 client section
```

I believe the issue is  in how I am configuring the Unifi cloud key to login to the radius server as its not showing a bad password error or good password error but I am not sure how to further tshoot thanks !

Answer (score 0):

the log shows that something in your clients.conf is not configured properly.

Client in this context is your AP, so the AccessPoint-IP has to be in that range.

[OpnSense client config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K05r1.png)